# Syncing remote and local failure

Tags: github, terminal

I am a noobie to terminal programming. I'm trying to delete a subfolder from a repository. The path is as follows:

```
CMSC764-Advanced-Numerical-Optimization/Homework-3/
```

This has two subfolders - MATLAB and Python and I want to delete the MATLAB one. I tried this: `git rm -r *.m` and this deleted the files locally. When I run `ls` , the MATLAB folder doesn't show.

I tried to commit the changes by `git push origin master` and it says `Everything up-to-date` but the MATLAB folder continues to exist on the remote.

There are several variations of these commits online and it's a lil puzzling.

Comment: have you committed the removal with `git commit`? from the description looks like the changes are not committed, so there is nothing to push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Committing is not "`git push`", but [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit):

```
git commit -m "delete files"
```

That will commit the index state, index which should reflect the `git rm` you did.

Then:

```
git push -u origin master
```

Comment: The above is rejected with this error message:

To https://github.com/dbhadra/CMSC764-Advanced-Numerical-Optimization.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/dbhadra/CMSC764-Advanced-Numerical-Optimization.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Comment: @db18a That is because other commits have been pushed while you were doing your local modifications.

Comment: @db18 Try and clone again the repository, delete again your folder, commit and push.